# Tkinter label has wrong output

Tags: python, tkinter, string-formatting

I have written python code with the aim to output MD5 hashes in the `tkinter.Label` widget but my output within the label is the following:

```
{filename: } llos.docx{  MD5:}312b1face983fe7ad82bd9909888680
```

Whereas, I would like the output to be the following which is displayed in my console:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents\Test
Filename:  cpck2.py      MD5:  1d05f6e9c551280098987dd32b64a2d
Filename:  llos.docx     MD5:  312b1face97877ad82bd87e4fa78680
```

Comment: md5 is considered unsafe nowadays.

Comment: This is a rather string issue I think so I replaced some of the tags.

Comment: You want the Label to show the same thing the terminal shows?

Comment: BTW, you need to restart the md5 for every file, otherwise the data from previous files is included in the hash. Move line 4 to line 8.

Comment: Yes i'd like to display the same as terminal in the label widget

Comment: The hashupdate.update(b"new values") creates an updated hash for each file but this is just a tester which i am creating

Comment: you have to format string and concatenate to one string before you use in label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print()` function allows you to concatenate objects that are separated by commas. This is the *only* place you can do this. In all other places, you need to do the string formatting yourself.

```
centerLabel['text'] = 'Filename: {}\t MD5:{}'.format(x, hashupdate.hexdigest())
```

Edit: or if you want all of them:

```
rootDir = r"C:\Users\Ghost\Documents\MalwareTest"
output = []
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=True):
    print('Directory:', dirName)
    for x in fileList:
        hashupdate = hashlib.md5()   
        with open(os.path.join(dirName, x), 'rb') as f:
            hashupdate.update(f.read())
        output.append('Filename: {}\t MD5:{}'.format(x, hashupdate.hexdigest()))
output = '\n'.join(output)
print(output)

centerLabel = Label(root, bg='white', width=65, height=13, padx=3, pady=3, anchor=NW,relief=SUNKEN)
centerLabel['text'] = output
```

(obviously totally untested)

Comment: The only problem is that one file is displayed at a time not like what is printed out in the terminal

Comment: Try again, I had to ninja edit one to many parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: @syedshah and if it still gives an error, it would help to know *what* error.

Comment: I have currently started programming as a hobby and trying to adjust to the stack overflow environment. Apologies for my lack of understanding. My code is now working. Thank you sir.

Comment: @syedshah make sure to select this answer and / or upvote it if it was helpful.